# Location of error report in magento Enterprise edition

Tags: magento-enterprise, error, ee-1.14

I am not able to get the location of error report while working in Magento Enterprise Edition 1.14.

I did not get anything in var folder of the site please help me.

[image]

Comment: If you need help debugging an error I would suggest http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store/429#429 is a great place to start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your reports should be in `/path/to/magento/var/report`.

If your permissions aren't set up correctly magento will not be able to write there. Try `chmod -R 777 /path/to/magento/var/report`. The folder should be owned by the same user that PHP-FPM or Apache is running as (depending on your setup). E.g `chown -R www:www /path/to/magento/var report` if PHP is running as `www`

Answer (score 2):

You should see a report folder under var where you can see the file with same name as per your screenshot.

If report folder is not there then there might be the permission issue. So give the proper permission on var folder and reload the magento website.